# How to parse JSON from a URL and display value in html

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am trying to get the value "shortmessage" and display it in the body of my HTML.  Below i what I have been messing with. Thank you for your help!

### JQUERY (that I am trying to use)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.myURL.com',
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
        //What I am trying
        $("body").append(JSON.stringify(010017.shortmessage));

    }
});
```

### JSON URL response

```
{"010017":{"shortmessage":"Jeans On Sale!","enddate":"10\/15\/2013 23:59:59","longmessage":"Save on your favorite Levi Jeans!","style":"010017"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` should have been assigned the response of the request. Ans, since it's JSON, it should have been converted to a native JavaScript object which makes the following feasible:

```
data['010017']['shortmessage']
```

You can use `obj['property']` notation since numeric values will cause you problems. As a heads up `obj.property` is synonymous with `obj['property']` in terms of access. You can also mix and match; so, given the above example, the below is the same:

```
data['010017'].shortmessage
```

Hacked together example: http://jsfiddle.net/r3K4W/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the data property in your success function.

```
$('body').append(data['010017'].shortmessage);
```

If you're using ASP.Net 3.5+ for the request, you may have to add `.d` do the data variable:

```
$('body').append(data.d['010017'].shortmessage);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C4v5B/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var jUrl = {"010017":{"shortmessage":"Jeans On Sale!","enddate":"10\/15\/2013 23:59:59","longmessage":"Save on your favorite Levi Jeans!","style":"010017"}};
alert(jUrl["010017"].shortmessage);
```